# How to smart search excluding specific expressions or letters?

Tags: smartsearch

When I do a search in the smart search component, I need the results to exclude some unique letters or expressions like: "a", "e", "de", "da", etc...

[image].

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Smart Search advanced usage - just click the advanced search button]

Per the "Advanced Search" options, "surrounding your query in quotes" will search for the exact phrase.